# Setting up RPi3 access point, hostapd error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

I've followed the following tutorials ([this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software) primarily, but [this also](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/)) to set up a wifi access point on my RPi3 (in order to then use it as a Tor proxy). I have reached the stage where I test the access point host by running:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

However, after inputting the command I receive the following error message:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
Could not set channel for kernel driver
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

Where should I be looking to troubleshoot this?

As additional information, I'm attempting to use the in-built RPi3 wifi adapter, and accordingly have commented out the **driver=rtl871xdrv** line in the **hostapd.conf** file.

Comment: I have the same problem :/ , you are found a solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and as usual with Linux, it's driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated.